# How to export a trained LGBM model and load it in c++

Tags: c++, python-3.x, lightgbm

I have trained a LGBM model in python:
clf=gbm.fit(X_train,y_train,eval_set=[(X_test,y_test)],early_stopping_rounds=5)

I want to use the trained model in c++,how should i export clf in python and load it in c++.
I want to predict in c++